# Is merging from updated remote or unpushed tracking branch the same?

Tags: git

Suppose, I have two feature branches `fb_a` and `fb_b` both checked out from `master` at the same point of time. Now, will the following sets of steps lead to the same final state with respect to `origin/fb_b` ?

Steps 1:

```
1) git checkout fb_a
2) git commit -m "change"            # commit some change
3) git push                          # push the changes
4) git checkout fb_b                 
5) git merge origin fb_a             # merge from remote branch
6) git push
```

Steps 2:

```
1) git checkout fb_a
2) git commit -m "change"            # commit the **same change**
3) git checkout fb_b                 # fetch the commit in fb_b
4) git merge fb_a                    # merge from tracking branch
5) git push
```

Kindly, provide any explanation towards the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both merges can be different (depends on the circumstances). In the first scenario, you merge the commit from origin/fb_a, from that state git last time saw where it pointed to. In the second scenario you take your current local revision.

Say the following is you current local repo, and you have two commits on fb_b, which are not at the remote repo:

```
    fb_a
o---A
 \
  o---OB----------o----B
      origin/fb_b      fb_b
```

The first merge will result in

```
         fb_a
o---A----M
 \      /
  o---OB----------o----B
      origin/fb_b      fb_b
```

The second merge will lead to

```
                         fb_a
o---A--------------------M
 \                      /
  o---OB----------o----B
      origin/fb_b      fb_b
```